# RDP Internal Error over SSL-VPN

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-8.1, vpn

I have a Windows 8.1 client that connects over SSL-VPN.

The SSL-VPN connects and I can see it on the firewall.  You can ping the remote computer (15-60ms with occasional 300+) with an average of 87ms over 114 packets.  As soon as you remote desktop to the remote computer the pings time out and a black screen is shown on the RDP.  After a short while the RDP errors with "Internal error occurred" and exits.

The pings continue to time out.  Exiting and restarting ping continues to timeout.  Waiting 30-45 seconds and restarting the ping will allow you to ping the host again.  The IP address shown in ping is correct.

All Windows updates with the exception of a .NET, Internet Explorer and 1 definitions update are installed.

Connection is directly client to remote computer running Windows 7.  I can RDP to remote computer from other devices/computers over VPN.  No connection brokers being used.  I have tried to RDP to the domain controller and other servers/computers and the same issue persists with those as well.

You can connect to UNC paths through the tunnel.

Event viewer logs show the VPN tunnel connection occurring but no other errors.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check for your vpn log because he don't like someting and he filter /drop paquets to the tunnel. Edit when you see someting usefull.

Comment: Determined it to be the DSL router.  When the computer was tethered off a cellphone it works perfectly.  Plug it back up to the router via cable or WiFi and it won't connect.  Not sure if it is a built in firewall or something with MTU settings possibly messing with it.

Comment: MTU was my immediate thought - perhaps lower the MTU in the VPN s/w if you can? Extremely unlikely to be the firewall.

Comment: 4 years later and I have the exact same problem - no solutions yet (just started to happen and affects other protocols like http & ftp) - its not the OS

Comment: @MC9000 The end user replaced their router and it began working.